Python logging object is being accumulating on each instantiation
Consider the following code, where I have created a custom logger class and then in a for loop I am creating logger object multiple times, but instead of adding one log at a time it is adding multiple logs as shown below
import sys
import logging
import os

import configs

class Logger:
    def __init__(self, logger_name='logger', log_file_name='logs.log'):
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(configs.LOGS_DIR, log_file_name))
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        self.logger = logger
    
    def get_logger(self):
        return self.logger

for i in range(5):
    logger = Logger(logger_name=f'test', log_file_name='test').get_logger()
    logger.info(i)

I was expecting this:
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 0
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 1
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 2
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 3
2024-12-20 21:17:09,642 - test - INFO - 4

but this is the output:
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 0
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 1
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 1
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 2
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 2
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 2
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 3
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 3
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 3
2024-12-20 21:17:09,623 - test - INFO - 3
2024-12-20 21:17:09,642 - test - INFO - 4
2024-12-20 21:17:09,642 - test - INFO - 4
2024-12-20 21:17:09,642 - test - INFO - 4
2024-12-20 21:17:09,642 - test - INFO - 4
2024-12-20 21:17:09,642 - test - INFO - 4

Why this is happening and how to fix this?

It happens because logging settings are persistent -- when you call logging.getLogger() the second time, it fetches the first logger object, including all of its handlers.  And then logger.addHandler() adds another handler, so you end up with five handlers all logging the same message.

The obvious fix is don't do it this way.  Create your logger object once.

How about placing this line logger = Logger(logger_name=f'test', log_file_name='test').get_logger() above the for loop?

I solved this issue by creating Logger class like this:
class Logger:
    @staticmethod
    def __create_file_handler__(log_file_path, level, formatter):
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_path)
        file_handler.setLevel(level)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        return file_handler
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_logger(logger_name='logger', log_file_name='logs.log'):
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        file_handler_file_path = os.path.join(configs.LOGS_DIR, log_file_name)
        file_handler_level = logging.INFO
        
        if logger.hasHandlers():
            file_handler = [_ for _ in logger.handlers if isinstance(_, logging.FileHandler)]
            
            if file_handler:
                file_handler = file_handler[0]
                if file_handler.baseFilename != log_file_name:
                    logger.removeHandler(file_handler)
                    logger.addHandler(Logger.__create_file_handler__(
                        file_handler_file_path,
                        file_handler_level,
                        formatter
                    ))
            
            return logger
        
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(Logger.__create_file_handler__(
            file_handler_file_path,
            file_handler_level,
            formatter
        ))

        return logger

And then use logger in the for loop like this
for i in range(5):
    logger = Logger.get_logger(logger_name=f'test', log_file_name='test')
    logger.info(i)

This solves the problem.
Thank you @john-gordon [John Gordon] For giving me a insight to think about it in another way.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
